# Does load_history view shows record for empty files loaded using copy into command?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Does load_history view shows record for empty files loaded using copy into command?

I know only successful copy statements are recorded in load_history but does it record empty file load?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tested, it does not look like LOAD_HISTORY records successful 0 processed files.

```
create or replace table test (a string);
create or replace stage test_stage;
copy into test from @test_stage;
+---------------------------------------+
| status                                |
|---------------------------------------|
| Copy executed with 0 files processed. |
+---------------------------------------+
```

And query to information_schema.load_history returned nothing.

But if I have one successfully loaded with records, then it shows up in the load_history.

I think it is because the history records processed files, as there is a FILE_NAME column. If no files processed, then it will not be recorded.